Evaluate a user provided logic statement in React
I have a JS object. I need to validate that object against a condition / logic statement that was provided via a CMS.
let logicFromCMS = "user.properties.phone.length != 10"

if (evaluateLogic(originalObject, logicFromCMS) {
   // sorry, this object is not valid
} else {
   // didn't match logic.
}

How can I do this safely in JS? This is part of a React application that will run on client side so I don't want the evaluateLogic function to have access to cookies or window or anything else. I obviously don't want to use eval();

just adding that I would want to do a complex expression.  ie: (a == b || (b > 32 && c< 25) || foo != bar)
